# GIMP plugins work only as root user

Tags: gimp

I'm new to Linux, and I can't use resynthesizer plugin without root permissions.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28Eu1.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iojwF.png)

If I run "sudo -i flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP" I don't have any errors.
My OS is Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: I assume you also installed the plugin as a flatpak?

Comment: Yup, using sudo flatpak install org.gimp.GIMP.Plugin.Resynthesizer//2-40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so previously I just put plugins.py everywhere where catalog was named "plug-ins" because I tried to make this plugin work on apt version of GIMP. To repair that I uninstalled app via `sudo flatpak remove org.gimp.GIMP`, went to root directory, searched for "plug-ins", "resynthesizer", "heal-", "gimp" and removed them. Next I typed `sudo apt autoremove`, just to make sure. Rebooted and installed a fresh version of GIMP via flatpak. Hope this helps someone.